# Using Python: excluding certain outputs (webpage titles)

Tags: python

Hello… I am using Python and BeautifulSoup to navigate the company’s webpages, verifying the validities of items.

Scripts as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import xlwt


pages = [36523,25658,85263,55215]

for page in pages:

    url = "http://company.com/" + page
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

    page_title = soup.find_all("title")
    print page_title
```

the outputs are:

```
[<title>Nil</title>]
[<title>Item details</title>]
[<title>Nil</title>]
[<title>Item details</title>]
```

There are some items don’t exists, the page title shows Nil. And I want to exclude these Nil in the output so I tired:

```
If len(page_title) == 20:
    Pass

If len(page_title) == 20:
    Continue

If page_title == ‘[<title>Nil</title>]’:
    Continue # or Pass
```

But all no successful and I am not heading the right direction. So how can I not have the Nil displayed in the results?

Thanks.

---

thanks to Ashoka Lella, below works when lower part is changed to:

```
page_title = soup.find_all("title")

for each_page in page_title:
    err_msg = soup.find_all(text="Nil")
    if len(err_msg) == 0:
        print each_page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tring to count length of `page_title` but, actually you should be counting the length of each element in `page_title`

if `page_title = ['<title>Nil</title>']`. then `len(page_title)=1` as its containing a single element but,`len(page_title[0]) = 20`

Thus, what you essentially should be doing is

```
for page in pages:
    url = "http://company.com/" + page
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    page_title = soup.find_all("title") #This will return a list of titles
    for title in page_title:
        if title != "<title>Nil</title>":
            print title
```

Comment: thanks Ashoka Lella. but it produces the same result.

Comment: by your guidance, i changed it a bit and it works! (please see modified original question)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
page_title = soup.find_all("title")
```

to:

```
page_title = (title for title in soup.find_all("title") if "Nil" not in title)
```

Comment: thanks, Adam Smith. but it generates results like "<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000056251F6>" etc...

Comment: @MarkK, using curved brackets `page_title=(...)` would return a generator object. But, it is iterable using `for`

Comment: thanks Ashoka Lella, this's out of my current knowledge but surely I will learn it.

Comment: @MarkK if you just want to print it, replace the outside `(...)` with `[...]`